# SQL query for counting changes of values in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

Given the following table structure:

| CAT | NR | DATE | VERSION | SOME_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 123 | 2009-02-19T00:00:00Z | 1 | OPP |
| ABC | 456 | 2009-03-18T00:00:00Z | 1 | ZUM |
| ABC | 444 | 2009-03-18T00:00:00Z | 1 | ZUM |
| ABC | 456 | 2009-04-18T00:00:00Z | 2 | XXX |
| ABC | 456 | 2009-04-18T00:00:00Z | 3 | XXX |
| ABC | 456 | 2009-04-18T00:00:00Z | 4 | UIO |
| ABC | 456 | 2009-05-18T00:00:00Z | 5 | RQA |
| ABC | 444 | 2009-03-18T00:00:00Z | 2 | MUZ |
| DEF | 789 | 2018-02-17T00:00:00Z | 1 | WER |
| DEF | 637 | 2018-02-16T00:00:00Z | 1 | FAW |
| GHI | 248 | 2018-02-17T00:00:00Z | 1 | QWE |
| GHI | 248 | 2019-02-17T00:00:00Z | 2 | PPP |
| GHI | 357 | 2020-02-16T00:00:00Z | 1 | FFF |
| GHI | 357 | 2020-02-16T00:00:00Z | 2 | GGG |
| GHI | 357 | 2020-02-16T00:00:00Z | 3 | LLL |
| GHI | 357 | 2020-02-16T00:00:00Z | 4 | LLL |
| GHI | 357 | 2020-08-16T00:00:00Z | 4 | FFF |
| GHI | 357 | 2020-10-16T00:00:00Z | 5 | ZZZ |
| GHI | 420 | 2020-02-16T00:00:00Z | 1 | QDS |

I need to find out how many effective changes took place in column SOME_CODE (sometimes values are the same and therefore they should not count) per month and category (CAT).

So expected SQL query result should like this:

| CAT | MONTH | SOME_CODE_CHANGES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | APR 2009 | 1 |
| ABC | MAR 2009 | 1 |
| GHI | FEB 2020 | 2 |

Does anybody have a hint how to start the query?

Within a category (e.g. ABC) I want to count number of changes in column SOME_CODE. When a changed happened (e.g. for NR=456) say from VERSION 1 to 2 ("ZUM" -> "XXX") I wanna count it but with two conditions:

- must be a change within a month
- must be an effective change. Means the change from VERSION 3 to VERSION 4 is a valid change ("XXX" -> "UIO") while the change from VERSION 2 to VERSION 3 is nonesense ("XXX" -> "XXX") and should not be counted

My approach:

```
select                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
trunc(DATE, 'MON'),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
CAT,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
sum(case when _MY_CONDITION_ then 1 else 0 end) counter                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
from table where date between TO_TIMESTAMP('01/06/2018 00:00:00.000000000', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF') and TO_TIMESTAMP('31/07/2018 00:00:00.000000000', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF')                                                                                           
group by                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    trunc(DATE, 'MON'),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    CAT                                                                                                                                                                                   
order by                                                                                                                                                                                         
trunc(DATE, 'MON')
```

Comment: Please explain how these numbers are calculated.  Why are you choosing only two months for the results?

Comment: What should be the output if a value changes from `ABC` to `DEF` and then back to `ABC`? Is that one or two changes?

Comment: @MT0 then it should count as twice changes (if within a month)

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added some more hints

Comment: **1.**  In your data you have three rows with the same `CAT`, same `DATE` and same `SOME_CODE`. How do you order such rows? "By date" doesn't suffice, since they have exactly the same timestamp. And, of course, different order may result in different counts of "changes".  **2.**  If the value changes from `'ZUM'` on February 26 to `'ZAM'` on March  2, is that a "change" you count for March? In almost any sane business use case the answer should be "yes" - but your explanation is confusing enough that MT0 assumed "no" for his answer. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT cat,
       month,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         TRUNC( "DATE", 'MM' ) AS month
  FROM   table_name t
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY cat, month
  ORDER BY "DATE", version
  ONE ROW PER MATCH
  AFTER MATCH SKIP TO LAST change_code
  PATTERN ( strt change_code )
  DEFINE
    change_code AS change_code.some_code <> strt.some_code
)
GROUP BY cat, month
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( CAT, NR, "DATE", VERSION, SOME_CODE ) AS
SELECT 'ABC',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2009-02-19 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'OPP' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',   456,    TIMESTAMP '2009-03-18 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'ZUM' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',   444,    TIMESTAMP '2009-03-18 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'ZUM' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',   444,    TIMESTAMP '2009-03-18 00:00:00 UTC',    2,  'MUZ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',   456,    TIMESTAMP '2009-04-18 00:00:00 UTC',    2,  'XXX' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',   456,    TIMESTAMP '2009-04-18 00:00:00 UTC',    3,  'XXX' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',   456,    TIMESTAMP '2009-04-18 00:00:00 UTC',    4,  'UIO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',   456,    TIMESTAMP '2009-05-18 00:00:00 UTC',    5,  'RQA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEF',   637,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-16 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'FAW' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEF',   789,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-17 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'WER' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   248,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-17 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'QWE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   248,    TIMESTAMP '2019-02-17 00:00:00 UTC',    2,  'PPP' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   357,    TIMESTAMP '2020-02-16 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'FFF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   420,    TIMESTAMP '2020-02-16 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'QDS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   357,    TIMESTAMP '2020-02-16 00:00:00 UTC',    2,  'GGG' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   357,    TIMESTAMP '2020-02-16 00:00:00 UTC',    3,  'LLL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   357,    TIMESTAMP '2020-02-16 00:00:00 UTC',    4,  'LLL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   357,    TIMESTAMP '2020-08-16 00:00:00 UTC',    4,  'FFF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   357,    TIMESTAMP '2020-10-16 00:00:00 UTC',    5,  'ZZZ' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> ```
> CAT | MONTH     | COUNT(*)
> :-- | :-------- | -------:
> ABC | 01-MAR-09 |        1
> ABC | 01-APR-09 |        1
> DEF | 01-FEB-18 |        1
> GHI | 01-FEB-20 |        3
> ```

If you want to see the changes then you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         TRUNC( "DATE", 'MM' ) AS month
  FROM   table_name t
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY cat, month
  ORDER BY "DATE", version
  MEASURES
    MATCH_NUMBER()     AS mn,
    FIRST( some_code ) AS change_from,
    LAST( some_code )  AS change_to
  ONE ROW PER MATCH
  AFTER MATCH SKIP TO LAST change_code
  PATTERN ( strt change_code )
  DEFINE
    change_code AS change_code.some_code <> strt.some_code
)
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> CAT | MONTH     | MN | CHANGE_FROM | CHANGE_TO
> :-- | :-------- | -: | :---------- | :--------
> ABC | 01-MAR-09 |  1 | ZUM         | MUZ      
> ABC | 01-APR-09 |  1 | XXX         | UIO      
> DEF | 01-FEB-18 |  1 | FAW         | WER      
> GHI | 01-FEB-20 |  1 | FFF         | QDS      
> GHI | 01-FEB-20 |  2 | QDS         | GGG      
> GHI | 01-FEB-20 |  3 | GGG         | LLL
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5cd7abfe8ec79935258ca2f9b4fb9b96)*

---

If your requirement for "within a month" is that you want changes where there is at most one month's difference between the previous row to the changed row, even if the rows are in two different calendar months, (rather than just the changes that happen in the same calendar month) then you can use:

```sql
SELECT cat,
       TRUNC( change_date, 'MM' ) AS month,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY cat
  ORDER BY "DATE", version
  MEASURES
    LAST( "DATE" ) AS change_date
  ONE ROW PER MATCH
  AFTER MATCH SKIP TO LAST change_code
  PATTERN ( strt change_code )
  DEFINE
    change_code AS (
      change_code.some_code <> strt.some_code
      AND MONTHS_BETWEEN( change_code."DATE", strt."DATE" ) <= 1
    )
)
GROUP BY cat, TRUNC( change_date, 'MM' )
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> CAT | MONTH     | COUNT(*)
> :-- | :-------- | -------:
> ABC | 01-MAR-09 |        2
> ABC | 01-MAY-09 |        1
> ABC | 01-APR-09 |        2
> DEF | 01-FEB-18 |        1
> GHI | 01-FEB-20 |        3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e24a048ed502a329369890c5b7cc614c)*

Comment: This can't be right, for a couple of reasons. First, you don't ever check change across month boundary (change in March, compared to last value from February). Second, the data in the OP's sample has duplicates by (CAT, "DATE"), so the problem is not even well-defined. The OP needs to clarify that point. In any case, if you change the very first row to have ZUM as CHANGE_CODE, your query still reports 1 change in March 2009, which can't be right - there are no changes that month.

Comment: @mathguy There is a change in March 2009 (from the 3rd to the 4th row of my data, its the 3rd and 8th row in the OP's data) and the OP only asks for "changes within a month" and this looks for changes that are within each calendar month.

Comment: Oh - I was wondering why I was still getting one change for that month (I didn't inspect the data closely). In any case - I believe if there are different values on Feb. 27 and then on March 5, then the change happened "within" the month. The OP needs to clarify that too (in addition to what to do when there are duplicate timestamps for a given CAT).

Comment: @MT0 fantastic! solved my problems very well - now I can start to play around - thank you and all other phenomenal inputs!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want one less than the number of distinct codes for each `cat` in each month:

```
select cat, trunc(date, 'MON') as yyyymm,
       count(distinct code) - 1
from t
group by cat, trunc(date, 'MON');
```

From what I can tell, this matches the results you specify.

Comment: But this is not correct if the change was like @MT0 told, true? If the change was from ABC to DEF and back to ABC your query would count 1 change - whereby there were effectively 2.

Comment: Second, distinct is not sufficient because a change relates only to a NR within a CAT.