# SQL query should count different entries but filter out duplicates when following one another

Tags: sql, oracle

Given a table structure like:

| CAT | BUSINESS_NR | TIME_A | VERSION | SOME_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 123 | 2009-02-19T00:00:00 | 1 | OPP |
| ABC | 456 | 2009-03-18 00:00:00 | 1 | ZUM |
| ABC | 444 | 2009-03-18 00:00:00 | 1 | ZUM |
| ABC | 444 | 2009-03-18 00:00:00 | 2 | MUZ |
| ABC | 456 | 2009-04-18 00:00:00 | 2 | XXX |
| ABC | 456 | 2009-04-18 00:00:00 | 3 | XXX |
| ABC | 456 | 2009-04-18 00:00:00 | 4 | UIO |
| ABC | 456 | 2009-05-18 00:00:00 | 5 | RQA |
| DEF | 637 | 2018-02-16 00:00:00 | 1 | FAW |
| DEF | 789 | 2018-02-17 00:00:00 | 1 | WER |
| SPZ | 123 | 2018-02-16 00:00:00 | 1 | AAA |
| SPZ | 123 | 2018-02-17 00:00:00 | 2 | BBB |
| SPZ | 123 | 2018-02-18 00:00:00 | 3 | AAA |
| SPZ | 123 | 2018-02-19 00:00:00 | 4 | CCC |
| SPZ | 123 | 2018-02-20 00:00:00 | 5 | AAA |
| SPZ | 123 | 2018-02-21 00:00:00 | 6 | DDD |
| SPZ | 123 | 2018-02-22 00:00:00 | 7 | DDD |
| SPZ | 123 | 2018-02-23 00:00:00 | 8 | DDD |
| SPZ | 123 | 2018-02-24 00:00:00 | 9 | EEE |
| SPZ | 123 | 2018-02-25 00:00:00 | 10 | EEE |
| SPZ | 123 | 2018-02-26 00:00:00 | 11 | DDD |
| SPZ | 123 | 2018-02-27 00:00:00 | 12 | BBB |
| SPZ | 123 | 2018-02-26 00:00:00 | 13 | EEE |
| SPZ | 123 | 2018-02-27 00:00:00 | 14 | EEE |
| GHI | 248 | 2018-02-17 00:00:00 | 1 | QWE |
| GHI | 248 | 2019-02-17 00:00:00 | 2 | PPP |
| GHI | 357 | 2020-02-16 00:00:00 | 1 | FFF |
| GHI | 420 | 2020-02-16 00:00:00 | 1 | QDS |
| GHI | 357 | 2020-02-16 00:00:00 | 2 | GGG |
| GHI | 357 | 2020-02-16 00:00:00 | 3 | LLL |
| GHI | 357 | 2020-02-16 00:00:00 | 4 | LLL |
| GHI | 357 | 2020-08-16 00:00:00 | 4 | FFF |
| GHI | 357 | 2020-10-16 00:00:00 | 5 | ZZZ |

... which one can easily create by:

```
CREATE TABLE blah (CAT, BUSINESS_NR, TIME_A, VERSION, SOME_CODE) AS
SELECT 'ABC',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2009-02-19 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'OPP' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',   456,    TIMESTAMP '2009-03-18 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'ZUM' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',   444,    TIMESTAMP '2009-03-18 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'ZUM' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',   444,    TIMESTAMP '2009-03-18 00:00:00 UTC',    2,  'MUZ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',   456,    TIMESTAMP '2009-04-18 00:00:00 UTC',    2,  'XXX' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',   456,    TIMESTAMP '2009-04-18 00:00:00 UTC',    3,  'XXX' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',   456,    TIMESTAMP '2009-04-18 00:00:00 UTC',    4,  'UIO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',   456,    TIMESTAMP '2009-05-18 00:00:00 UTC',    5,  'RQA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEF',   637,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-16 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'FAW' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEF',   789,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-17 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'WER' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SPZ',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-16 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'AAA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SPZ',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-17 00:00:00 UTC',    2,  'BBB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SPZ',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-18 00:00:00 UTC',    3,  'AAA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SPZ',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-19 00:00:00 UTC',    4,  'CCC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SPZ',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-20 00:00:00 UTC',    5,  'AAA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SPZ',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-21 00:00:00 UTC',    6,  'DDD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SPZ',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-22 00:00:00 UTC',    7,  'DDD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SPZ',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-23 00:00:00 UTC',    8,  'DDD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SPZ',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-24 00:00:00 UTC',    9,  'EEE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SPZ',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-25 00:00:00 UTC',    10, 'EEE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SPZ',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-26 00:00:00 UTC',    11, 'DDD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SPZ',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-27 00:00:00 UTC',    12, 'BBB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SPZ',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-26 00:00:00 UTC',    13, 'EEE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SPZ',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-27 00:00:00 UTC',    14, 'EEE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   248,    TIMESTAMP '2018-02-17 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'QWE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   248,    TIMESTAMP '2019-02-17 00:00:00 UTC',    2,  'PPP' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   357,    TIMESTAMP '2020-02-16 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'FFF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   420,    TIMESTAMP '2020-02-16 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'QDS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   357,    TIMESTAMP '2020-02-16 00:00:00 UTC',    2,  'GGG' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   357,    TIMESTAMP '2020-02-16 00:00:00 UTC',    3,  'LLL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   357,    TIMESTAMP '2020-02-16 00:00:00 UTC',    4,  'LLL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   357,    TIMESTAMP '2020-08-16 00:00:00 UTC',    4,  'FFF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   357,    TIMESTAMP '2020-10-16 00:00:00 UTC',    5,  'ZZZ' FROM DUAL
```

... I want to count each change of SOME_CODE for each CAT per month.
A change means a change of SOME_CODE within a Business_nr.

I started with the following approach:

```
select cat, moenat, sum(counta) from (
select 
cat, 
trunc(TIME_A, 'MON') as moenat, 
count(distinct SOME_CODE) as counta
from blah
group by cat, BUSINESS_NR, trunc(TIME_A, 'MON')
) z
group by cat, moenat
order by cat, moenat
```

... which outputs almost what I want:

| CAT | MONTH | sum(counta) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SPZ | FEB 2018 | 5 |
| ... | ... | ... |

But I need all real changes AND the condition: filter out duplicates that are coming one after the other,
like I can demonstrate by CAT='SPZ':

| CAT | BUSINESS_NR | TIME_A | VERSION | SOME_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SPZ | 123 | 2018-02-21 00:00:00 | 6 | DDD |
| SPZ | 123 | 2018-02-22 00:00:00 | 7 | DDD |
| SPZ | 123 | 2018-02-23 00:00:00 | 8 | DDD |

and so on.

So for SPZ: versions 6 to 8, 9-10 and 13-14 should count each as one (not three or two times) because there was no effective change going on.

That means the expected query output (in FEB 2018) for CAT='SPZ' therefore must be like:

| CAT | MONTH | sum(counta) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SPZ | FEB 2018 | 10 |
| ... | ... | ... |

... for 10 times there was an effective change of the code (starting value with version 1 'AAA' must count too, because each record indicates a change).

FYI:
maybe parts of the solution (MATCH_RECOGNIZE) of this topic could help:
[SQL query for counting changes of values in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66564773/sql-query-for-counting-changes-of-values-in-a-column/)
but I am not sure.

Hint: order is defined by higher version number as well as time_a information.

Thanks for any new appoach.

Comment: Yes, MATCH_RECOGNIZE might work well; see https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=Match-Recognize-Examples-SQL-Pattern-Matching

Comment: Your example for SPZ is clear, but the business nr is same for all records. What output would you want to see for GHI ? If there is only 1 row, for a business nr/month combo, does that count as a change ? Do you look within a business nr but across months ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `LAG` function to look at the previous version to see if `some_code` matches the current version, then `SUM` to get the total of all the code changes.

```sql
  SELECT cat, moenat, SUM (version_change) AS total_version_changes
    FROM (SELECT cat,
                 TRUNC (TIME_A, 'MON')    AS moenat,
                 CASE
                     WHEN    some_code <>
                             LAG (some_code) OVER (PARTITION BY cat ORDER BY version, time_a)
                          OR LAG (some_code) OVER (PARTITION BY cat ORDER BY version, time_a) IS NULL --Needed for version 1
                     THEN
                         1
                     ELSE
                         0
                 END                      AS version_change
            FROM blah)
GROUP BY cat, moenat
ORDER BY cat, moenat;

   CAT       MOENAT    TOTAL_VERSION_CHANGES
______ ____________ ________________________
ABC    01-FEB-09                           1
ABC    01-MAR-09                           2
ABC    01-APR-09                           2
ABC    01-MAY-09                           1
DEF    01-FEB-18                           2
GHI    01-FEB-18                           1
GHI    01-FEB-19                           1
GHI    01-FEB-20                           4
GHI    01-AUG-20                           1
GHI    01-OCT-20                           1
SPZ    01-FEB-18                          10
```

Comment: seems to be almost fully correct. Only thing I am thinking about is the case: GHI    01-FEB-20                           5... here I would expect 4 because LLL shall be counted as duplicate.... strange because it seems to work for: SPZ 123 2018-02-27 00:00:00 14 EEE

Comment: @DerBenniAusA - You are correct. I have modified the window clauses of the `LAG`s to correct the issue. Please look at the updated answer.